# How can I order response based on dynamic key

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a below data  response which I want to order based on specific fields (fields should be configurable so that later we can change the ordering key like f_name, city, type... any of from the nested list of dict)

```
data = [{"type":"single",
    "ra":"SI-11", 
    "name":{
        "f_name":"Jon",
        "l_name":"Devi", 
        "prefix":"Mr"},
    "addresses":[{
        "address": "123St",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY"
        },
        {
        "address": "14St",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY"
        }],
        "racks": ["racks1", "rack2"],
    },
    {"type":"multiple",
    "ra":"SI-44", 
    "name":{
        "f_name":"Patrik",
        "l_name":"Dev", 
        "prefix":"Mr"},
    "addresses":[{
        "address": "333St",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY"
        },
        {
        "address": "14000St",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY"
        }],
        "racks": ["racks1", "rack2"],
    }]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The idiomatic way if to use `sort` or `sorted` with an appropriate key function. `functools.cmp_to_key` is a nice tool for easily writing a key function comparing multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define custom key function, which would accept for the path to search for in the nested structure:

```py
data = ...  # List[Dict]

def key_resolver(path):
    def function(x):
        value = x

        for key in path.split('.'):
            value = value.get(key, {})

        return value

    return function

# use case
sorted(data, key=key_resolver('name.f_name'))  # delimit nested keys using "." (dot)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response however it is throwing below error... any idea on this?
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: can you please share the `path` value? I think you've passed it in wrong format, or key path does not exist

Comment: path value - name.f_name

Comment: for key in path.split('.'):
            result = x.get(key)

this is trying to get both the keys (name and f_name) from x
in the second iteration result is having None

Comment: sorry, my bad, instead of result, should have used `value` as return variable name - fixed the answer

Comment: issue still persist . because 
for key in path.split('.'):
            value = x.get(key)
    will always get None in second iteration

Comment: no, it won't. Assuming you pass `name.f_name` as path, for first iteration value would be equal to the dict under the `name` key, on second iteration, value would be equal to the `f_name` key value.

If I just copy & paste your data and my code, it works, please check carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235127/discussion-between-iceman-and-giorgi-jambazishvili).